# How to get 3d direction vector of a 2d function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a function $f(a,b)$, where I can plot it on a 3d graph, using $a$ and $b$ as $x,y$ coordinates and $f(a,b)$ as the $z$ coordinate (i.e. https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html). How can I get the direction vector $(u,v,w)$ of the slope at point $(a,b,f(a,b))$?

The direction of the arrows should go at angle $\theta$.

Thanks

Comment: The direction is given by the angle $\theta$. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I figured it out, its (u,v,w) =  (cos(theta), sin(theta),  (df/dx)(x,y) * cos(theta) +   (df/dy)(x,y) * sin(theta))